# Why does the regex work not as expected?

Tags: c#, regex

There is a string which can have one or several string ranges.
These are correct strings:

```
""
"asd-asd"
"asd-asd;asd-asd"
"asd-asd;asd-asd;"
"asd-asd;asd-asd;asd0-asd1"
```

But the string `"asd0-asd1-asd2"` shouldn't be valid. I wrote the following regexp:

```
^(([^;-]+-[^;-]+);?)*$
```

And it doesn't work as I expected - this regexp shows that this string is match. Why?

Comment: Because the `;` is optional, it could match it as two groups - `asd0-asd` and `1-asd2`. Just trying to work out a clean way to get around that.

Comment: Would `";"` be a valid match? If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your regex a little more complicated:

```
^([^;-]+-[^;-]+(;[^;-]+-[^;-]+)*)?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Start of the string
(               # Start of first group:
 [^;-]+-[^;-]+  # Match one "asd-asd"
 (              # Start of second group
  ;             # Match ;
  [^;-]+-[^;-]+ # Match another "asd-asd"
 )*             # Repeat the second group any number of times (including zero)
)?              # Make the entire first group optional     
$               # End of string
```

Comment: (You can also use non-capturing groups (`(?:...)` instead of `(...)`), but the regex is hard enough to read as it is - some people think that the slight performance benefit isn't worth it.)

Answer (score 1):

It matches because of ;? which makes the ; optional. You are trying to test something with context, regex is not the easiest tool to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid making the semicolon optional, instead you could use (;|$).
This will force the match of a semicolon unless you are at the end of the string.

```
^(([^;-]+-[^;-]+)(;|$))*$
```

Comment: No. A dash is considered a literal if it's in the last position in a character class. All regex engines behave like this.

Comment: Not much better. `[;$]` means "Match a `;` or a `$` character". Regex metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class.

Comment: How about this version?  I actually tested it this time.  Seams ok.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight add to the Answer of @Tim. This regex is not matching the "asd-asd;asd-asd;" if you're using .Net regex library. But if you add a ';' as option before string ends then it'll cover all the cases.

```
^([^;-]+-[^;-]+(;[^;-]+-[^;-]+)*);?$
```

Now this will match all the valid strings provided except the Invalid - "asd0-asd1-asd2"

Comment: +1, thanks for noticing! However, now it doesn't match the empty string any more.